# C++ run one cpp file from all files in visual studio project

Tags: c++

I have a project related to maths and in that I have multiple independent C++ scripts in that project. Is it possible to only build an executable of a single file rather than the whole project, instead of creating multiple projects.

Edit: I have bunch of independent files:
Primes.cpp
Fibonacci.cpp
etc.

I want to run each one individually, as they are all independent scripts. Take an example in PyCharm, when you make a project and run, it only runs the file that is currently open, not the whole project.

I want to do this in C++, only run a specific file of a project, not run the WHOLE project. I prefer not having many projects as that would mean many, many projects.

Answer (score 0):

An executable is created, based on files, of which the main one contains the `main()` function (in the generally accepted form). If you can create such a main function, you might actually create such an executable, but I'm afraid that it won't do what you want: can you edit your question and explain us what you want to achieve? (I might edit my answer accordingly)

Answer (score 0):

No, you should put them in separate projects. Visual Studio is not built for running single-file C++ scripts.

> #### [Projects and Solutions in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/solutions-and-projects-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019)
>
> ... In a logical sense, a project contains all files that are compiled into an executable, library, or website.

Projects are designed to hold all the source and configuration for building, debugging, linking, running, etc. a single executable/library. Do not be afraid of having many projects. I have a long-running solution much like you with many single-file one-off projects.